# Topology of a home network (with Wi-Fi)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

What kind of topology is the setup you'd typically find in homes where a [residential gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residential_gateway) provides internet access and connects consumer devices like laptops, PCs, and mobile phones?

I'm assuming here that the residential gateway acts as:

- a modem for connecting to the ISP's network using, e.g., DSL or DOCSIS,
- a router, also for connecting to the ISP's network,
- a switch for wired Ethernet connections to the end devices,
- and as an access point for wireless connections using Wi-Fi, also for end devices.

Judging from [this video](https://youtu.be/zbqrNg4C98U?t=283) by PowerCert Animated Videos, this setup would be classified as an *infrastructure topology*.

Is that correct?

I'm interested in the topology inside the home, not the topology that the ISP might use for their routers.

---

<sub>Meta: This question was originally asked [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81160/topology-of-a-home-network-with-wi-fi) at Network Engineering but was closed since home networking questions are off-topic.</sub>

Comment: It varies widely - and don't forget there's fibre optic as well now

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I tried to make the question more precise via an edit: It's only the topology of described setup *inside the home* (the LAN) I'm interested in, which is pretty common from my experience.

Comment: These small home-setups are usually not given a formal topology description. Mostly because the modem/router/ap/switch all-in-one device is the whole thing with all all end-devices connecting directly to it in most cases. And when we are discussing and comparing network topologies we usually deal with much bigger/complexer setups. To me it just doesn't make much sense to try to classify a home-setup in terms of topologies. It is pretty academic and has no real practical use to do so.

Comment: @Tonny: As mentioned in a comment to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1762689/topology-of-a-home-network-with-wi-fi#answer-1762692), I also question whether it makes sense to classify this setup using a topology. Which begs the question if it's still worthwile describing larger setups using topologies. Setups such as those of companies, schools, or universities that extend the home setup with multiple switches and wireless APs.

Comment: It is useful as long as you know the *scope* of such descriptions – star/bus/ring still apply to individual parts of the network, just not to the entire network anymore. (Usually the entire network can be considered a spanning tree, which is for some reason never included in those topology lists, even though you would encounter STP/RSTP on just about every large network.) For example, it is somewhat common to have the centre of a "star" itself be a ring of Ethernet switches that STP prunes into a tree (disabling one of the ring links); if one of the ring links is cut, STP reactivates another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that correct?

Yes, partially, but also no.

The video mixes up two different *kinds* of labels. "Ad Hoc" and "Infrastructure" are specifically names of 802.11 Wi-Fi operation modes – they do not quite fit in the same list as "Star" or "Bus", although each mode does *form* a certain network topology.

"Infrastructure" is indeed the mode that most Wi-Fi networks use – it's the operation mode where clients connect to access points (i.e. the AP is the "infrastructure"). However, 1) it only applies to Wi-Fi specifically; 2) it's not a name of a network topology at all. Any Wi-Fi network, on its own, would be a "bus" network physically (as it runs over a shared radio link at the physical layer or L1) regardless of the mode.

The Wi-Fi operation mode also doesn't describe the rest of the network beyond that single Wi-Fi SSID. You also have an Ethernet network connected to it, which forms a "star" topology (with the switch at its center and both the router's CPU and the Wi-Fi access point as connected nodes).

So at physical layer (L1) you have **two** networks with their own topologies – 1) a switched Ethernet network that forms a star of full-duplex links, and 2) a Wi-Fi network that's more of a half-duplex bus topology (or two of them if the access point is dual-band). The Wi-Fi access point is a bridge that interconnects the two networks (it's a node on both), and the result is no longer exactly like any of the basic topologies (just like the result of gluing a basic cube to a basic cylinder is no longer a simple shape).

---

At link layer (aka MAC layer or L2), however, the Wi-Fi network behaves more like a "star" – when "Infrastructure" mode is used, clients do not send frames directly to each other but only through the access point, similarly to how Ethernet switches relay all frames.

So at link layer, the topology of a home network with Wi-Fi looks like two interconnected stars, or a *spanning tree.* (I would draw it as a tree with the Ethernet switch as the root; the router CPU, the access point, and all wired Ethernet devices as one level deep; and all Wi-Fi devices as two levels deep.)

This topology is invisible to devices, though – a device doesn't know that it's sending MAC frames through a switch or through an access point; it just specifies the MAC address of the destination device, so even switched Ethernet still behaves like old-school bus Ethernet (except it's full-duplex so not really a bus).

(For Wi-Fi, the WLAN interface's firmware automatically converts between Ethernet-like frames on the OS side and 802.11 frames on air. The 802.11 frame *does* have the AP's MAC as a destination, but the OS doesn't see this.)

In other words, the entire home network works like a spanning tree at "lower" link layer, but pretends to be something like a flat bus network at "upper" link layer.

Note that the modem isn't part of the network at this point yet – it's behind a router (which is a network layer or L3 gateway), so it does not participate in the home network's L2 or L1 topology at all. Instead, the modem is part of the ISP's network.

Comment: I thought so too, that calling the infrastructure mode a topology was a bit odd. But the video's author says that the wired part of the network is "very similar to a star topology". As a side note, I find it stunning that a common setup like this doesn't fall neatly into a single topology. Maybe topologies aren't a useful abstraction here.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Modern ethernet wired networks are always star topologies (either wired as such or wired as a mesh that that gets reduced to a star by spanning-tree) and that is what every home setup uses, so obviously it looks like one. I agree that topology abstractions are not really useful here.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: The wired part of the network _is_ a star topology with the Ethernet switch at the center (even the CPU and the AP are connected to internal "ports" of the same switch). But at the same time, the wired part of the network is not "ad-hoc" or "infrastructure" if those are used as technical terms, as both of those come specifically from 802.11 Wi-Fi and apply to each Wi-Fi device individually (even a regular home network can have an Infrastructure-mode SSID for clients, provided by multiple physical access points, and a Mesh-mode SSID to connect them together...)

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: As for the side note, each of those topologies only describes an isolated (one level deep) network that has no outside connections. But the fact remains that this common setup consists of two or three networks (an Ethernet star or spanning-tree; a Wi-Fi bus on the 2.4 GHz band; and another on 5 GHz), so you have two different topologies connected together and there's no longer a common description for them.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: It is also that the same network can have multiple topologies at different layers. For example, old Ethernet with taps coming off shared coax looked like a bus _and_ worked like a bus. With twisted-pair going through a hub, though, it became star if you looked at the wiring (everything going through a hub) but still a half-duplex bus if you looked at the signals. (With switched Ethernet, it fully became a star of full-duplex links.) Similarly, as mentioned, Wi-Fi fits the description of a "bus" physically, but forms a star at link layer (MAC layer) with the AP at the centre.

Answer (score 0):

In networking jargon, "topology" is primarily used in comparing data link layer (layer 2) technologies, as most link layer technologies were designed to use a single topology (star, bus, ring, mesh, tree, etc.). If you have a network that uses a mix of link layer technologies that use different topologies, such as the typical home network that you described, then your network is simply a mix of topologies.